# Is it possible to raid or be in the same league as a clanmate in multi-player?

Tags: clash-of-clans

In Clash of Clans, we have clans; a collection of people donating and fighting with each other.
However, I have a clan made up of pretty much people nearly the same trophy levels as me.

Is it possible for clanmates to be matched against me (or vice versa) in Multiplayer battles or be in the same league?

Comment: No, you can't unless you leave the clan and get paired up with them, but I can't find an actual source to cite here so I'll avoid posting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

[You cannot attack a member of your own clan.](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/24297-Is-it-possible-to-attack-one-s-own-clan-member) If a user gets attacked, joins the attacker's clan, and then clicks "revenge", it will give you an error message stating you cannot attack members of your own clan.

You can, however, be in the same league as clanmates, since it is random. League information is shown [here](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Trophy_Leagues). This happens often for the top clans that make it to legend/near legend ranks, since there are so few at the top. It is statistically improbable though, in lower ranks. There's a lot of people down there.

Answer (score 0):

- When you enter a league, you are paired with random people to help you measure your progress.
- You cannot attack your own clan mates.

You can find more info in here:
http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Trophy_Leagues

Comment: Actually, it is possible to be paired in the same clan as one of the random people matched for your league; check Bunyip's [comment](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/199004/is-it-possible-to-raid-or-be-in-the-same-league-as-a-clanmate-in-multi-player/199008#comment269209_199004)

Comment: And great job citing the wiki. Have you actually done any research on it? (Testing)

Comment: @aytimothy I don't know where that "actually" makes references since I didn't mention it in the post, but I can edit it to add this fact; and I've obviously done more research than just opening the wiki, apart that I'm an elder player in this game.

Comment: Elder? Elders are only elevated clan members. I'm one too!

Comment: @aytimothy You can be an elder member in a game as well as you can be an elder member in a clan or in any other field. Go troll somewhere else.

Comment: @Jerry Where's your proof for your second point?